# 3 Month free only on first installation

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, restore, keychain

I need to implement a system where when the user install my app for the first time, he has 3 month of free use.
After three month the app has to show in-app purchase options.
I need to avoid that if the user remove and reinstall app, he can again use three month of free use.
I thought to use InApp purchase (a free, Non-Consumable item) to achieve my goal.
Using 'Non-Consumable' I have that 'SKPaymentTransaction *originalTransaction' contains the date of original transaction, so I can know If 3 month are expired or not and if the user reinstall or install the app in other devices, he can restore the remaining days using the same iTunes account.
Unfortunatly Apple reject the app using this reasons:

"
11.7: Apps that use IAP to purchase items must assign the correct Purchasability type
11.7

We found that the Purchasability Type for one or more of your In App Purchase products was inappropriately set, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.

'3 mese' is set to Non-Consumable. However, based on product functionality, it would be more appropriate to use the Non-Renewable Subscription In App Purchase type because the service offered by your application requires the user to make an advance payment to access the content or receive the service.
"

They suggest me to use Non-Renewable Subscription, but I dont have free price in Non-Renewable Subscription, so its useless for me.

In wich way I can achive my goal ?

Should I use KeyChain to store some identifier ?
But in this way the user will have 3 month in each device and I will not able to identifier uniquely on my server and, in addition, formatting the iphone he will have another 3 months of free use

Maybe in the app could I force the user to create an account on my server (or unsing parse.com for example) to have 3 month free ? Anyway the user could create several fake accounts except if I ask for personal data as phone number...but I think that Apple could reject the App if I ask personal data

What is the best choice be adopted in these cases?

Comment: It's simply not possible to do this.

It goes against the absolute basic model of apps on iPhones.

Answer (score 0):

For this I would firstly, create a back-end system. Possibly using Parse.com. Then I would register the users UDID when they sign up to the app. This way its the device that they have registered not just the app. Then create a code that will allow them to access the app but perform a check in the database on parse to see whether or not they are allowed the free content. If not, then show the payment options.

Comment: It's forbiden to track UDIDs, you should rather use accounts.

Comment: This is totally wrong, you can't use the UDID.  Read up on the new "advertising convenience token" -- and what you can and can't do with it.

Comment: Also FWIW everyone has many devices these days.  All of the systems such as Unity3D's that use the wifi card identifier and the like .. get broken every year by Apple when Apple clamps down on it.  It's just a non-starter -- it's not how apps work.